# Класс в классе

Tags: ооп, классы, php, объекты

Здравствуйте! 
Появилась задача реализовать следующие.
 Есть класс modules
После чего он расширяется

```
 Class open extends modules
    {
    function functione()
    {
      echo "Module loaded";
    }
  }
```

Я хочу что бы этот класс был доступен так
    $modules->open->functione();
Каким способом можно это реализовать?

Comment: Собственно а к чему это, поясните пожалуйста? Если для читабельности, то можно назвать класс open_modules, и тогда обращение к функции будет иметь вид 
    $modules_open->functione();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, в общем-то, говорите не про классы, а про свойства. Самое простое решение - с помощью магии:

```
class ModuleStorage
{
    protected $storage = array();
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->storage[$name])) {
            return $this->storage[$name];
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function __set($name, $module)
    {
        $this->storage[$name] = $module;
    }
}

class Open
{
    public function x()
    {
        echo 'I\'m both alive and a legitimate president of Ukraine';
    }
}

$modules = new ModuleStorage;
$modules->open = new Open;
$modules->open->x();
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить более подробней эти строчки
public function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->storage[$name])) {
            return $this->storage[$name];
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function __set($name, $module)
    {
        $this->storage[$name] = $module;
    }

Comment: Это [магические методы][1], которые позволяют записать или прочитать несуществующее свойство экземпляра класса.

    $modules = new ModuleStorage;
    $modules->open = new Open; // у класса ModuleStorage нет свойства open, но его можно установить
    $modules->open->x(); // ... и прочитать


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите на реализацию [компонент и модулей в фреймворке Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent)

Например

```
Yii::app()->cache->get('key')
```

на самом деле читает конфиг для компоненты `cache`, и берёт оттуда имя класса. Затем инстанциирует экземпляр класса с параметрами, заданными в конфиге же и сохраняет инстанс в реестре компонент под кодом `cache`. При последующем запросе Yii::app()->cache инстанс с кодом `cache` берётся из реестра.

Answer (score 0):

нет, так не получится. только если в классе "modules" (лучше переименовать в module) сделать метода вроде add_module, и после добавления open обращаться к нему как в свойству modules